# Implementation HTTP synchronous request response in kafka

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka

I am working on containerization application where a front-end application calls HTTP request to API gateway. The request data received at API Gateway is forward to Micro service via Kafka. But I have to send the response back the result as response back to API gateway and back to front-end application.
Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve the synchronous request and response between API gateway and micron service via Kafka.

I have tried with Producer and Consumer, which is like Fire and forget where I am unable to respond back the request.

Thanks in Advance.

Arun

```
using Confluent.Kafka;


Producer Code
using var p = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build();
 // Send the message to our test topic in Kafka                
                var dr = await p.ProduceAsync("test", message);


Consumer Code

using var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build();
  c.Subscribe("test");
 // Consume a message from the test topic. 
                    var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);
```

Comment: any reason why you use the Kafka in middle of API gateway and application? Directly calling to application will solve the problem.If still wants to use async communication, client needs to poll for result perodically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your right, you probably want to setup something like a request/response RPC queue in Kafka.  The API (producer) will drop the request into the requestKafka, and the micro service (consumer) will pick it up for processing.  When the response is ready, the micro service (producer) will drop the response into the responseKafka to be picked up by the API gateway (consumer).  Finally the API gateway will deliver the response back to the front end. You need to figure out how to associate the response from the micro service back to the client who made the original call. The RPC request/response is asynchronous. You can make a synchronous call by having the API directly call the micro service without involving Kafka.

Comment: Hi sanmcp, thank for you reply.
  Actually, what I am trying to implement is since the major business login and DB transaction are on micro services. Due to this I should able to scale in or scale out the micro service only. I have already worked on such Architecture using Java and Rabbit MQ using rabbitmq listener. But now requirement is on .NET core and Kafka. Please let me know if you have come across such requirement and how can we achive.
Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

implementing kafka event driven means that you may not receive the response in order that you sent the response.
so if you need to handle it in sync just follow with api calls instead of using kafka, also you still be able to scale out your project in sync call with increasing number of pods per each microservice.

**but if you need to keep kafka as is:**
when a request comes from UI to microservice and microservice sent it to kafka immediately return and unique number like objectId (if you presist request in db) to your front-end, and then front-end can make a http get call with unique number after a some seconds to get the result.